# Getting graph attributes from JSON file with d3.js

Tags: json, d3.js

You can easily get the node/link attributes from a json file using the d3.js library.
Is it possible to get the **graph** attributes ?
Sample JSON file:

```
{"directed": true, "graph": 
[["name", "()"], ["label", "Graph Attribute"]], 
"nodes": [
{"node_attr": 1.0, "id": "001"}, 
{"node_attr": 0.5, "id": "002"}
```

...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`d3.json` returns a JSON that you can do whatever you want to. Within the callback, just access the keys that you need (`mydata.graph` for example). Do you have specific code that you need assistance with?